# C# A random BigInt generator

Tags: c#, biginteger, dsa

I'm about to implement the [DSA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm), but there is a problem:

> choose "p", a prime number with L bits, where 512 <= L <= 1024 and L is a multiple of 64

How can I implement a random generator of that number? `Int64` has "only" 63 bits length.

Comment: standard comment: "That's OK for study/experimentation but don't you dare use that in production".

Comment: Also see [Chew Keong TAN's BigInteger class](http://www.weblearn.hs-bremen.de/risse/RST/WS06/single_vs_dual/sources/BigInteger.cs)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can generate a random number with `n` bits using this code:

```
var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] bytes = new byte[n / 8];
rng.GetBytes(bytes);

BigInteger p = new BigInteger(bytes);
```

The result is, of course, random and not necessarily a prime.

The [BigInteger class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207(v=VS.100).aspx) was introduced in the .NET 4.0 Framework.

---

For generating large prime numbers, [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes):

> For the large primes used in cryptography, it is usual to use a modified form of sieving: a randomly-chosen range of odd numbers of the desired size is sieved against a number of relatively small odd primes (typically all primes less than 65,000). The remaining candidate primes are tested in random order with a standard primality test such as the Miller-Rabin primality test for probable primes.

So you could do something like this:

```
var p = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfCandidates)
                  .Select(i => RandomOddNumber(bits))
                  .Where(x => !primesLessThan65000.Contains(x))
                  .Where(x => PrimalityTest(x))
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @AakashM - Likely enough. Guessing is a good strategy for getting a prime number, not to mention a prime random number.

Comment: Why are you dividing by 8? Does that ensure it to be a multiple of 64 ?

Comment: i downvoted because `Random` class is not good for cryptographic purposes. and your quote from wiki gives only slight sense of how to make prime.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @Filip Ekberg: I'm dividing the number of bits by 8 to get the size of the byte array, because there are 8 bits in a byte.

Comment: @dtb this is much better. But i think that security is the place where you should not reinvent bicycles and use well proven implementations, because your system might be vulnerable, or algorithm inefficient. i am sure that there are very well done algorithms for key generation for DSA

Comment: @Mitch Wheat public **abstract** class RandomNumberGenerator

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Is `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` preferable to `new RNGCryptoServiceProvider`?

Comment: Don't you need to add a `00` byte as MSB so the sign is always positive?

Comment: @Andrey - [Can computers generate a truly random number](http://engineering.mit.edu/ask/can-computer-generate-truly-random-number).  Whether he uses the crypto library or not, is kind of irrelevant as neither is capable or true random numbers. Crypto just offers a slightly more advanced algo for generating. The quote on there from random.org following it [random.org](https://www.random.org/) states that it uses "atmospheric noise" as it's method, which is, an algorithm.  While the seed is larger, it is still not truly random, but it is more complex.

Comment: @SamuelJackson using "atmospheric noise" is not an algorithm. It is not a computer that generates random number, computer here merely observe an a outside randomness. Computer here is not a RNG, atmosphere is.

Comment: "A randomly-chosen range of odd numbers of the desired size is sieved against a number of relatively small odd primes (typically all primes less than 65,000)" doesn't translate to `.Where(x => !primesLessThan65000.Contains(x))`. To "sieve" using all primes less than 65,000 means to eliminate any number that is a *multiple* of one of those smaller primes.