# How to Random a biginteger in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, biginteger

i have a problem when generate a random number,
for example i want generate a random number  between 2 to 579018135005309

i try function random in vb.net, but it cant compute a **BigInteger**

```
Function RandomNumber(ByVal min As BigInteger, ByVal max As BigInteger) As BigInteger
     Static Generate As System.Random = New System.Random()

     Return Generate.Next(min, max)
 End Function
```

any other way to get random number from a big value?

Comment: There is a good answer [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2965707/1070452) it is in c# but very easily converted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert on randomness, but thought this could be a fun little function to make.

A part of this answer is from the link in the comments above (C# A random BigInt generator), but extended to the requirement for them to be within a certain range.

This is what I came up with:

```
Public Function GenerateRandom(min as biginteger, max as biginteger) As BigInteger

    Dim bigint As BigInteger

    Do
        ' find the range of number (so we can generate #s from 0 --> diff)
        Dim range as BigInteger = max - min

        ' create random bigint fitting for the range
        Dim bytes As Byte() = range.ToByteArray()
        Using rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
            rng.GetBytes(bytes)
        End Using

        ' ensure positive number (remember we're using 0 --> diff)
        bytes(bytes.Length - 1) = bytes(bytes.Length - 1) And CByte(&H7f)

        ' add minimum to this positive number so that the number is now 
        ' a candiate for being between min&max
        bigint = min + New BigInteger(bytes)

        ' since we now only have a random number within a certain number of
        ' bytes it could be out of range. If so, just try again.

    Loop While (bigint > max)

    ' we have a number in the given range!
    return bigint 

End Function
```

Comment: thx,, its solved my problem, but actually i didnt know hot it work , whats inside >RNGCryptoServiceProvider()< .

Comment: It generates random numbers: https://www.dotnetperls.com/rngcryptoserviceprovider

Comment: Btw, updated the method with a using statement around RNGCryptoServiceProvider.

Comment: The recursive call is a [bit like this](https://xkcd.com/292/).  No guarantee that it will *never* bomb with this site's name, the OP's choice for *bigint* is almost as bad as possible with  ~12.3% odds that it will recurse.  Well, you'd have to be unlucky.  It just isn't necessary when you can loop.  Or use BigInteger's % operator (requires more bytes).

Comment: Haha - had not seen that xkcd. You are right of course, but unless the stack is very small, the probability of a raptor attack might actually be higher than getting a stack overflow =P. But given the infinite monkey theorem and all that, I've updated the answer.